# Object not found in shiny server - works outside the server

Tags: r, shiny

I'm learning a bit of shiny right now and have an issue here. I'm declaring a variable "finaldata" which refers to a column in my "asylum" dataset. When printing this variable(column), it works fine, as does using the block of code outside of the shiny server wrapper.

However, once I try to refer to finaldata within my ggmap function, it gives me an "object not found" error.

It doesn't seem to matter where i declare my reactive finaldata, it seems to give me the error regardless.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why the code would work outside of the server wrapper, and has no issues printing finaldata, but when it comes to putting it inside the ggmap function it breaks? Thanks for any help!

```
server <- function(input, output) {

finaldata <- reactive({asylum[,(input$Yearin - 1995)]})

output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

asylummap <- ggmap(map) +
  geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat, size = finaldata, stroke = 1), data = asylum, alpha = 0.7) +
  scale_size(range = c(1,20))    
asylummap
})

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific about the error message. Which object is not found? Anyways, the following code works well for me

```
library(shiny)
library(ggmap)

## code from ?ggmap
mu <- c(-95.3632715, 29.7632836); nDataSets <- sample(4:10,1)
chkpts <- NULL
for(k in 1:nDataSets){
  a <- rnorm(2); b <- rnorm(2);
  si <- 1/3000 * (outer(a,a) + outer(b,b))
  chkpts <- rbind(
    chkpts,
    cbind(MASS::mvrnorm(rpois(1,50), jitter(mu, .01), si), k)
  )
}
chkpts <- data.frame(chkpts)
names(chkpts) <- c("lon", "lat","class")
chkpts$class <- factor(chkpts$class)

## adapted from OP
finaldata <- reactive({chkpts[, "class"]})
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(plotOutput("plot")),
  server = function(input, output, session){
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      ggmap(hdf, extent = "normal") +
        geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat, colour = finaldata()), data = chkpts, alpha = .5)
    })
  }
)
```